# i have a function in which i am using bulk bind and passing multiple i/p parameter using in operator its not getting binded

Tags: plsql

```
create or replace type branch_warehouse as object (wh_id number,wh_name varchar2(100))

create or replace type id_warehouse_list as table of branch_warehouse

function get_ware_house_branch(p_BRANCH_IDS varchar2) return id_warehouse_list is
  l_warehouse_list id_warehouse_list := id_warehouse_list();
  str varchar2(300);

 begin
  str := 'SELECT BRANCH_WAREHOUSE(w.wh_id, w.wh_name)
            FROM POD_WAREHOUSE_MASTER W
            where ( W.BRANCH_ID  IN  (:'|| p_BRANCH_IDS||'))';

  execute immediate str bulk collect into l_warehouse_list using  p_BRANCH_IDS; 

  return l_warehouse_list;
```

end;

if i use single i/p parameter using = : it gets binded, please guide

Comment: Is `p_BRANCH_IDS` a comma-separated list of values? The ':' in the SQL string shouldn't be there. And I think the `using p_BRANCH_IDS` should be removed from the `execute immediate`.

Comment: yes thats y i have used in operator

Answer (score 1):

Re-write your function as follows:

```
function get_ware_house_branch(p_BRANCH_IDS varchar2)
  return id_warehouse_list
is
  l_warehouse_list id_warehouse_list := id_warehouse_list();
  str varchar2(300);
begin
  str := 'SELECT BRANCH_WAREHOUSE(w.wh_id, w.wh_name)
            FROM POD_WAREHOUSE_MASTER W
            where ( W.BRANCH_ID  IN  (' || p_BRANCH_IDS || '))';

  execute immediate str bulk collect into l_warehouse_list; 

  return l_warehouse_list;
end;
```

This seems to work properly (see [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f655f/3)).

The only changes I made were those suggested in my earlier comment - the ":" was removed from the SQL string, and the `using p_BRANCH_IDS` was removed from the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: i am not getting the o/p if i use only wh_id